# python function call by using for loop can i change the number in the function name

Tags: python, function, loops, for-loop, call

I have a function1, function2, function3, function4.
actually, I want to call the function with for loop
like,

```
for i in range(..):
  function(i)
```

can i change the number in the function name?

Comment: You might be able to do it with `eval`, assuming you know what you're doing.

Answer (score 2):

Not recommended, since this is bad practice unless you know what you're doing:

You can use `eval` for this:

```py
for i in range(..):
   eval(f'function{i}()')
```

Another similarly not-recommended way that use the same principle is using `globals()` if your function is defined globally, or `locals()` otherwise:

```py
for i in range(..):
   globals()[f'function{i}']()
```

A better way to do it is to have a list of functions you want to run, then loop through it:

```py
fns = [function1, function2, function3, function4, ...]
for fn in fns:
    fn()
```

Yes, you can have a list of functions in Python.

Comment: Or a dictionary